# Syntax error when querying SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table containing a date field. I saved the date field when creating the table as Integer.  The user choose the date using a date picker and the date is stored in the format: dd/mm/yy.
I want to return the rows in the table where dates in the field  date > current date
I tried the following query:

```
public Cursor getUpcomAp ( ) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery (" select * from " + TABLE_NAME2 + "where strftime('%d.%m.%Y', date) > now.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')" , null);
        return res;

}
```

The application crashes when I click on the button that execute this query.
Here is the logcat output:

```
    01-02 13:09:39.250: D/(918): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb882df30, tid 918
01-02 13:09:39.400: W/EGL_emulation(918): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-02 13:09:39.410: D/OpenGLRenderer(918): Enabling debug mode 0
01-02 13:09:57.690: D/dalvikvm(918): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 109K, 6% free 3263K/3448K, paused 197ms, total 210ms
01-02 13:09:58.570: W/EGL_emulation(918): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-02 13:10:01.770: E/SQLiteLog(918): (1) near "(": syntax error
01-02 13:10:01.780: D/AndroidRuntime(918): Shutting down VM
01-02 13:10:01.780: W/dalvikvm(918): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a5eba8)
01-02 13:10:01.820: E/AndroidRuntime(918): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 13:10:01.820: E/AndroidRuntime(918): Process: com.example.appointapp, PID: 918
01-02 13:10:01.820: E/AndroidRuntime(918): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "(": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: select * from appointments_table where strftime ('%d.%m.%Y', date) > now.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
01-02 13:10:01.820: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
01-02 13:10:01.820: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
01-02 13:10:01.820: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
01-02 13:10:01.820: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
01-02 13:10:01.820: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
01-02 13:10:01.820: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
01-02 13:10:01.820: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
01-02 13:10:01.820: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
01-02 13:10:01.820: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
01-02 13:10:01.820: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at com.example.appointapp.DatabaseHelper.getUpcomAp(DatabaseHelper.java:86)
01-02 13:10:01.820: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at com.example.appointapp.AppointFragment$5.onClick(AppointFragment.java:189)
01-02 13:10:01.820: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
01-02 13:10:01.820: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
01-02 13:10:01.820: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-02 13:10:01.820: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-02 13:10:01.820: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-02 13:10:01.820: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
01-02 13:10:01.820: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 13:10:01.820: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-02 13:10:01.820: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
01-02 13:10:01.820: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
01-02 13:10:01.820: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help

Comment: Yes use `TABLE_NAME2 + " where` need to add space before `where`

Comment: Thank you but am still facing the same problem after adding a space, plz help if u can

Comment: Sure show updated logcat output

Comment: i just did it. thank you in advance

Comment: What is `date ` a column name?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I was just going to ask the same thing.. +1

Comment: yes, here is the code when i created the table : db.execSQL( "create table "+ TABLE_NAME2 + "( IDAP INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, DATE INTEGER, TIME INTEGER, IDP INTEGER REFERENCES patients_table(ID))");

Comment: Isn't it ambiguous ? (the `DATE` type & the **date** column + try changing the column name or the date separator that you are using)

Comment: @javaprogammera: As see http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html `%d.%m.%Y` is also not valid date format

Comment: plz note that i changed date to datte and it is still giving the same logcat output. plz can u suggest which date separator to use. kindly note that i am saving datte as integer. Thank you

Comment: and i've changed the date separotor : public Cursor getUpcomAp ( ) {
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
  Cursor res = db.rawQuery (" select * from " + TABLE_NAME2 + "  where strftime ('%Y-%m-%d', date) > now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')" , null);
  return res;
 and i am still facing the same problem... plz help if u can

Comment: Thank you for the correction, help and suggestions.  I change the type of the field into text, arrange my format in the datapicker and change the code into: Cursor res = db.rawQuery ( " select * from " + TABLE_NAME2 + "  where date (datte) > date ('now') " , null ); and it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
where strftime('%d.%m.%Y', date) > now.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
```

`strftime()` always wants the data value as a parameter. (And `now` is not a special column name; only the string `'now'` is handled specially.)

Furthermore, `dd/mm/yy` is not one of the [supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html); `strftime()` just returns NULL for your values. Additionally, a string in the format `dd.mm.yyyy` cannot be compared correctly with string comparisons.

Store the dates in a supported format like `yyyy-mm-dd`. Then you can compare the values directly:

```
where date > date('now')
```

Comment: This is what i did (u can check in the above comments). Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 4):

You need a space before `WHERE`:

```
"where strftime('%d.%m.%Y', date)....
```

should be

```
" where strftime('%d.%m.%Y', date)...
```

*(`SELECT * FROM table_nameWHERE...`, this is the result you had)*

Comment: Thank you but am still facing the same problem after adding a space, plz help if u can

Answer (score 0):

Have to give Space between `TABLE_NAME2` and `where`:

```
Cursor res = db.rawQuery (" select * from " + TABLE_NAME2 + " where strftime('%d.%m.%Y', date) > now.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')" , null);
```

Comment: Thank you but am still facing the same problem after adding a space, plz help if u can